# convert UTF 16 file to UTF 8 using C# and Notepad

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have a file that is in Unicode 16.  Or in Notepad when I go to File > Save As ... Notepad just reads the file as UNICODE.  My other options are UTF 8, UNICODE, and TXT.  I have been having to manually re-save this file as a UTF 8 in Notepad.

Is there any way to have C# do this for me?

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: Why would you want to write a C# program to do something you can do by hand in 10 seconds with Notepad?

Comment: Anything to avoid Notepad... But maybe the OP has a lot of those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ex. ConsoleApplication

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class ConvertUTF16toUTF8 {
    static int Main(string[] argv){
        if(argv.Length != 2){
            Console.WriteLine("conv InputFilePath OutputFilePath");
            return -1;
        }
        File.WriteAllText(argv[1], File.ReadAllText(argv[0], Encoding.Unicode), Encoding.UTF8);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what method your using to write files. You can usually specify an encoding.

```
File.WriteAllText(path, contents, Encoding.UTF8)
```